# Ajax call throwing off anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I current have a page that displays from top to bottom: a responsive table containing a list of classes my company offers, a map showing the location of each class, and an agenda for the class. My employer would like me to add an anchor link in another page that links directly to the agenda portion of the page.

The issue that is that when the anchor is clicked, the user is redirected to the agenda (the desired result), but then the ajax call to the server finishes and the table above expands and pushes the agenda down.

I have tried to wrap the table in a div with a calculated height based on the contents of the table, but the min-height seems to be applied after the fact.

Here is the url for the anchored link: http://www.grastontechnique.com/clinicians/M1_Trainings#m1-training-agenda

I will also include the code snippets pertaining to the table and ajax calls.

Here is the call to the server

```
$scope.loadData = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getTrainings", "Clinicians")',
            data: { "trainingType": "M1" },
            success: function (data) {
                newData = JSON.parse(data)
                index = 0;
                tableHeight = 77;
                trainingsTable = document.getElementById("m1-trainings-table-container");
                newData["records"].forEach(function (object) {
                    if (newData["records"][index]["Early_Bird_Discount_Amount__c"] > 0)
                    {
                        tableHeight += 141;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tableHeight += 125;
                    }

                    newData["records"][index].firstDayStartTime = BuildTimeString(new Date((newData["records"][index]["First_Day_Start__c"].slice(0, -9) + "Z").replace('+', '.')));
                    newData["records"][index].firstDayEndTime = BuildTimeString(new Date((newData["records"][index]["First_Day_End__c"].slice(0, -9) + "Z").replace('+', '.')));
                    newData["records"][index].lastDayStartTime = BuildTimeString(new Date((newData["records"][index]["Final_Day_Start__c"].slice(0, -9) + "Z").replace('+', '.')));
                    newData["records"][index].lastDayEndTime = BuildTimeString(new Date((newData["records"][index]["Final_Day_End__c"].slice(0, -9) + "Z").replace('+', '.')));

                    newData["records"][index]["First_Day_Start__c"] = new Date((newData["records"][index]["First_Day_Start__c"].slice(0, -9) + "Z").replace('+', '.')).toDateString();
                    newData["records"][index]["Final_Day_Start__c"] = new Date((newData["records"][index]["Final_Day_Start__c"].slice(0, -9) + "Z").replace('+', '.')).toDateString();

                    index += 1;
                });
                trainingsTable.style.minHeight = tableHeight + "px";
                $scope.trainingsList = newData['records'];
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
```

And here is the table container

```
<div class="container spaced-container" ng-app="trainingsApp">
<div class="row" ng-controller="trainingsController">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h3 class="training-section-header text-center">M1-Basic Training Schedule</h3>
        <p class="text-center">To qualify for the Early Bird Special (Save $50) your registration must be paid for anytime 30-days prior to your training date.<br />
        <input type="text" id="zip-input" class="locate-a-provider-input" style="margin: 25px auto; padding-left: 5px;" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search Trainings"></p>
        <div id="m1-trainings-table-container">
            <table class="table table-responsive calculator">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10%" class="vertical-centered-parent"><p>State</p></th>
                        <th style="width: 35%" class="vertical-centered-parent"><p>Location</p></th>
                        <th style="width: 35%" class="vertical-centered-parent"><p>Time &amp; Date</p></th>
                        <th style="width: 20%" class="vertical-centered-parent"><p>Register</p></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="table-row vertical-centered-parent" ng-repeat="training in trainingsList | filter:searchQuery as results">
                        <td class="state-td vertical-centered-parent" id="responsive-state-parent">
                            <span class="responsive-table-spans">State: </span>
                            <p class="responsive-paragraph">{{training.Venue_State__c}}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="location-td vertical-centered-parent">
                            <p class="min-width">
                                <span class="responsive-table-spans">Venue:<br /></span>
                                {{training.Venue_Name__c}}<br />
                                {{training.Venue_Street_Address_1__c}}<br />
                                {{training.Venue_City__c}}, {{training.Venue_State__c}} {{training.Venue_Postal_Code__c}}
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="time-date-td vertical-centered-parent">
                            <p class="min-width">
                                <span class="responsive-table-spans">Dates:<br /></span>
                                <span style="color: #F57149" ng-if="training.Capacity_Full__c > 80 && training.Capacity_Full__c < 99.99">Closing Soon<br /></span>
                                <span style="color: #F57149" ng-if="training.Capacity_Full__c >= 100">Wait List<br /></span>
                                <span style="color: #F57149" ng-if="training.Early_Bird_Discount_Amount__c > 0 && training.Capacity_Full__c < 100">Early Bird Special: Save ${{training.Early_Bird_Discount_Amount__c}}!<br /></span>
                                {{training.First_Day_Start__c}}<br />
                                {{training.firstDayStartTime}} - {{training.firstDayEndTime}}<br />
                                {{training.Final_Day_Start__c}} <br />
                                {{training.lastDayStartTime}} - {{training.lastDayEndTime}}<br />
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="sign-up-td button">
                            <button class="rounded-button button-sign-up" ng-click="toTraining(training.Id)">Sign Up</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Danny D.

Comment: I hesitate to put this as an answer because it is so "hackish". You could fix this by setting `window.location = window.location.href;` at the end of your success callback after all the content has been updated by the ajax call. This will effectively scroll the window to the anchors "new" location. I did test this on the BIG 3 (IE, FireFox, Chrome) and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately this just lead to an endless loop of page reloading. I appreciate the suggestion though!